# Change order of geo coordinates python

Tags: python, coordinates, geojson, shapely

I have a `pandas` dataframe containing `MULTIPOLYGON` coordinates in `(LON`, `LAT)` format. I need to use this coordinates to add a polygon to an `ipyleaflet` map but I need to change the order of the coordinates to `(LAT`, `LON)`

```
df['Footprint'][0]

''MULTIPOLYGON (((-3.870231 39.827106,-3.49322 41.329609,-6.624273 41.739006,-6.931492 40.237854,-3.870231 39.827106)))''


# Here in locations, I have manually changed the order
polygon = Polygon(
    locations=[(39.827106,-3.870231),(41.329609,-3.49322),(41.739006,-6.624273),(40.237854,-6.931492),(39.827106,-3.870231)],
    color="green",
    fill_color="green"
)

m = Map(center=(39.5531, -3.6914), zoom=6)
m.add_layer(polygon);
m
```

Any idea on how to do the trick?

Comment: Check this answer from GIS Stack Exchange: [Interchange y, x to x, y with geopandas (python) or QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/312082/142375)

Comment: @Georgy not very clear how to adapt that code to my example as my coordinates are a `str` and not a `geometry` object. Any suggestion?

Comment: How about something like `gdf.geometry.map(lambda polygon: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y: (y, x), shapely.wkt.loads(polygon)))`?

Comment: Getting the following error: `'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'geometry'`

Comment: For your dataframe it should be `df['Footprint'].map(lambda polygon: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y: (y, x), shapely.wkt.loads(polygon)))` I guess.

Comment: Any updates on the problem? You could write an answer if you solved it.